# Finding local minima exactly

Tags: mathematical-optimization

Is there a way to either make `FindMinimum` do an exact computation or `Minimize` find also the local minima? Or other ideas to find local minima exactly?

**Example:** find all local minima (exact values, not approximations) of $f(x,y)=x^2 − x + 2y^2$ on $E=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 : x^2+y^2\le 1\}$.

Comment: We need an example from you to see what the problem is. `FindMinimum` usually does what is required. What do you mean by exact?

Comment: @Hugh, thanks for the comment, I have added an example.

Comment: @MaurizioMoreschi, What do you mean as search for minima "exactly"? The numerical search is exact enough or you need the analytical solution?

Comment: @Rom38 I want the EXACT solutions, so no numerical method of any sort can be used

Comment: One may find all the critical points of that differentiable function through `Reduce[{D[x^2 - x + 2*y^2 D[x^2 - x + 2*y^2, x] == 0, x] == 0, 
  D[x^2 - x + 2*y^2, y] == 0, x^2 + y^2 <= 1}, {x, y}, Reals]` . Its behavior on the boundary should be studied separately.

Comment: @user64494, yes like that I know how to do it in general. However, I was wondering if there were pre-implemented functions that deal with the boundary altogether. Of course, my question mainly about what happens on the boundary.

Comment: `FindMinimum` might also find a global min and miss local ones. To get all of them in some region one can set up a KKT solver.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Yes, I think that is probably the best way to go. It's just that I wanted to use this for an exercise class, but the students have not learned Lagrange multipliers yet. I guess that for the moment I will just analyse the boundary separately. Thank you all for the comments.

Comment: For an exercise class I think I'd go with a cardio machine over a Lagrange multiplier. Just my preference.

Answer (score 7):

**Extrema on the edge.**

```
f = x^2 - x + 2 y^2;
g = x^2 + y^2 - 1;
L = f + \[Lambda] g;

pts = Solve[{Grad[L, {x, y}] == 0, g == 0}, {x, y, \[Lambda]}];
points = pts[[All, 1 ;; 2]];
critpts = Thread@{f /. points, points};
```

bordered Hessian:

```
hesseMatrix = {{0, D[g, x], D[g, y]}, {D[g, x], D[L, x, x], 
     D[L, x, y]}, {D[g, y], D[L, y, x], D[L, y, y]}} /. pts;
detHesse = Det /@ hesseMatrix
{-4, 6, 6, -12}

max = Cases[Thread@{Sign /@ detHesse, critpts}, {1, _}][[All, 2]];
min = Cases[Thread@{Sign /@ detHesse, critpts}, {-1, _}][[All, 2]];
sol = Association["Minima" -> min, "Maxima" -> max]
```

[image]

**Extrema within the region.**

```
sol2 = Solve[{Grad[f, {x, y}] == 0, x^2 + y^2 < 1}, {x, y}];
globalMin = Thread@{f /. sol2, sol2}
```

[image]

```
Eigenvalues@D[f, {{x, y}, 2}] /. sol2
{4, 2}
```

Eigenvalues are positive; this is the global minimum.

```
reg = ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 <= 1, {x, y}];
Show[
 Plot3D[f, {x, y} \[Element] reg, Mesh -> 10, 
  MeshFunctions -> {#^2 + #2^2 &}, PlotTheme -> "FilledSurface"],
 Graphics3D[{
   Red, PointSize@0.03, Point[{x, y, f} /. sol["Minima"][[All, 2]]],
   Green, PointSize@0.03, Point[{x, y, f} /. sol["Maxima"][[All, 2]]],
   Blue, PointSize@0.03, Point[{x, y, f} /. globalMin[[1, 2]]]}]
 ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The exact minimization of a function can be done using `Minimize`:

```
  f[x_, y_] := x^2 - x + 2 y^2
  sol = Minimize[f[x, y], {x, y}]
  (*{-(1/4), {x -> 1/2, y -> 0}} <= output of Minimize*)
  Show[
    Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] Disk[{0, 0}, 1]],
    Graphics3D[{Red, PointSize[Large], 
       Point[Flatten@{{x, y} /. sol[[2]], sol[[1]]}]}]
  ]
```

[image]

Comment: I want all the points of LOCAL minima

Comment: @Maurizio, for `Minimize[]`, you need to separately consider the boundary: `Minimize[{f[x, y], x^2 + y^2 == 1}, {x, y}]`

Comment: @MaurizioMoreschi, do you really think that your function has more than one minima? it is possible just if you know an alternative algebra..

Comment: @Rom38 Hahaha, that was not really my point, but I understand the misunderstanding! I gave the numerical example because people asked for it in the comment. Your method of course finds the point of minimum it this case, but it uses the information that the minimum is strong and absolute!

Comment: @MaurizioMoreschi, working with arbitrary function you should divide the domain to sub-domains and run the minimization inside all of them. Thus, you will have all local minima.